# finished tic tac toe on python

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop, counter

I have this project and I can't figure out how to check if x or o won. Also I don't know how to check if x or o was played too many times using the count function because of the way I appended my list. You will understand that in my code:

```
if user_option == 0:
        print("option 0")
        print ("For each row, start with x. Enter a combination of x's "\
            "and o's up to three characters. For a blank space," \
            "enter a period '.'.")
        msg = [ "top row", "middle row", "bottom row"]
        col_size = 3
        row_size = 3
        ttt = list()
        for n in range(col_size):
            rows = input(msg[n]+ ":")
            ttt.append(rows)
        print(ttt)
        valid_symbols = ['x','X','o','O','.']
        done= False
        for i in ttt:
            if len(i) < 3:
                print("invalid board - too few symbols")
                break
            elif len(i) > 3:
                print("invalid board - too many symbols")
                break
            for x in i:
                if x not in valid_symbols:
                    print("invalid board - invalid symbol "\
                        + x )
                    done = True
                    break
                else:
                    continue
            for o in i:
                if o not in valid_symbols:
                    print("invalid board - invalid symbol "\
                        + o)
                    done = True
                    break
                else:
                    break
```

Comment: You really should have just edited your previous question to contain this information.

Comment: @WayneWerner I did but I got no response

Comment: And what does that tell you?